# Live USB not booting in Lenovo Ideapad s10-3

Tags: 10.10, lenovo

**Ubuntu 10.10 Live usb not booting in Lenovo Ideapad s10-3**. I install ubuntu desktop edition in my pen driver using "Startup Disk creator". But this live usb is not booting on my netbook(Lenovo S10-3).

Comment: Please edit your question to include a few more details. Have you tried it on other computers? What happens when you try to boot your lenovo off the USB drive?

Comment: Have you tried it on other computers?Yes I tried it on the other computers.it works very well.But not working in Lenovo s10-3    What happens when you try to boot your lenovo off the USB drive?It shows Black screen with blinking cursor.

Comment: I  cannot boot also. I have tired the procedure that was described on the ubuntu page. tried both ways, linux and windows. When I boot, the menu appears and when I run it such as try Ubuntu or Install, nothing happens it just gives a BEEP.nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

There's a kernel bug specific to your Lenovo S10-3: [bug #634702](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/634702).  It's also in the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MaverickMeerkat/ReleaseNotes#Boot,%20installation,%20upgrade%20and%20post-install):

> Lenovo S10-3 systems don't boot.
>   Temporary workaround: add
>   "intel_idle.max_cstate=0" as a kernel
>   paremeter at boot ([634702](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/634702)). A fix
>   already exists that will be available
>   only at release time ([647071](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/647071)).

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/syslinux/+bug/617779 Looks like something is broken in syslinux/usb-creator so you cannot boot from a USB made by usb-creator in Maverick. Unetbootin works though..

Answer (score 1):

This was covered in the Ubuntu 10.10 [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MaverickMeerkat/ReleaseNotes#Common%20Desktop%20Applications):

> It is not possible to create Ubuntu 10.04 USB disks from the Startup Disk Creator
> in Ubuntu 10.10 due to a backwards incompatibility in the syslinux program.

It has been reported as bug [645818](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/645818)

Comment: Have you tried it on other computers?Yes I tried it on the other computers.it works very well.But not working in Lenovo s10-3    What happens when you try to boot your lenovo off the USB drive?It shows Black screen with blinking cursor.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it, hope it helps anyone else with the same problem.

http://technomess.blogspot.com/2010/11/ubuntu-1010-and-lenovo-ideapad-s10-3.html